# How to accelerate loading resource file in J2ME

Tags: file, java-me, resources, loading

I'm writing a J2ME application using J2ME Wireless Toolkit 2.2
I have the following code:

```
public class BusReader
{

  private String[] fileNames;
  private final String allFilesInfoFile = "files_in_dir";

  public BusReader ()
  {
  fileNames = getFileNames ();
  String busNo = getBusNo ("BusNo1p.bin");
  }

  public String[] getAllBusFiles ()
  {
  return fileNames;
  }

  public String getBusNo (String fileName)
  {
  String[] fileLines = loadResourceFile (fileName);
  int linesCount = fileLines.length;

  for (int i=0;i<linesCount;++i)
    if (fileLines[i].equals ("[BusNo]") && i < linesCount-1)
      return fileLines[i+1];

  return null;
  }

  public String getDefaultDirection (String fileName)
  {
  String[] fileLines = loadResourceFile (fileName);
  int linesCount = fileLines.length;

  for (int i=0;i<linesCount;++i)
    if (fileLines[i].equals ("[BusDirection]") && i < linesCount-1)
      return fileLines[i+1];

  return null;
  }

  private String[] getFileNames ()
  {
  return loadResourceFile (allFilesInfoFile);
  }

  private String[] loadResourceFile (String fileName)
  {
  String content = "";

    try
    {
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName), "iso-8859-2");
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(1024);
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int read;

    while ((read=in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
      temp.append(buffer, 0, read);

    content = temp.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
    }

  int len = content.length ();

    if (content.charAt (len-1) == '\n' && content.charAt (len-2) == '\r')
    {
    String newContent = "";

      for (int i=0;i<len-2;++i)
        newContent += content.charAt (i);

    content = newContent;
    }

  String[] fileLines = TString.Split ("\r\n", new TString(content));

  for (int i=0;i<fileLines.length; ++i)
  {
    fileLines[i] = fileLines[i].trim ();
      if (fileLines[i].length () == 0)
        fileLines[i] = "";
  }

  return fileLines;
  }
}
```

All works correctly, but the problem is when I'm trying to copy my application into mobile phone. On my mobile phone when I open the application before application show I must wait 35 seconds. This is because, constructor executes the function twice:

```
loadResourceFile (String fileName)
```

which loads the resource file. Files size which function is loading are: 1.22KB and 29KB.
The question is: How to accelerate loading function (loadResourceFile)?

I tried to create java class files as resource data but it exceeded java memory limit. I changed arrays String[][][][] to String[][][] and it was loading on my mobile phone in 15 seconds. I thought when I will load data as a resource it will work faster. My mobile phone: Nokia 3110c

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
It was following lines (it takes 35 seconds):

```
if (content.charAt (len-1) == '\n' && content.charAt (len-2) == '\r')
{
String newContent = "";

  for (int i=0;i<len-2;++i)
    newContent += content.charAt (i);

content = newContent;
}
```